# Saving text to a file when a QPushbutton is pressed

Tags: c++, qt

I have been login for a way to save some text to a file when I press a QPushbutton and I was wondering if anyone could lead me to somewhere to find out?
I am programing in qt 5.12 with C++.

Comment: Use signals and slots.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:
.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFile>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
    button->setText("Push Here");
    button->setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 30);
    button->show();
    //signal and slot connection
    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::writeSomeText);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::writeSomeText()
{
    QFile n_file("file.txt");
    if(n_file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))  //open a file
    {
        n_file.write("Some Text");  // write on a file
        n_file.close();  //close the file
    }
}
```

.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void writeSomeText();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Please be sure to check [Signal And Slot doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) and [QFile Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) to better understanding of the code.

Answer (score 0):

use a QFile and a QTextStream, open the file with readWrite flags stream the text whenever you need

```
void MainWindow::on_Button_clicked()
{
    QString filename{"MyFile.txt"};
    QFile file{filename};
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << "Hello World" << endl;
        file.close();
    }
}
```